# iTunes no identities are available for signing has gone from bad to worse

Tags: ios, xcode, sdk, ios7.1

So I was getting the *no identities are available for signing* error when I tried to upload my app, and I tried a number of ways to fix this.

That was a very bad idea. 
I tried revoking my certificates and now it's telling me 
No matching provisioning profiles found: None of the valid provisioning profiles include the device Justin's iPad (identifier: 5858525b2680f4b92838cd5d54e3c56bcb1edf98).

> CodeSign error: code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 7.1'

And under preferences, accounts it says the iOS Development is missing the private key.

I am completely and totally lost on what to do to fix this.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently had this same problem. The mysterious message about the development profile is particularly telling - we should not be talking this way, because App Store is distribution, not development. Proceed as follows:

1. Look in your keychain with Keychain Access. You will probably see that the iOS Distribution certificate has gone bad or is missing entirely. So that's the place to start. Go back to the Member Center and get yourself a working Distribution certificate and get rid of the old one, deleting it entirely from the Member Center (that's important).
2. Now throw away your distribution profile both in Xcode and at the Member Center. Make a new distribution profile and download it. Adjust your build settings to match the new profile!

The reason for the whole problem is that the Member Center will happily make you a distribution profile with a bad certificate, and that's what you had. There is no easy way to detect that this has happened because it's hard to distinguish *what* certificate the distribution profile is using. You need to make sure that there is a good distribution certificate *and that it is the only distribution certificate* so that you can be sure that when you make the distribution profile, the good distribution certificate is used.

Comment: +1 to you too... when one works on-site at different locations with multiple computers, I've found this can be a frequent problem if one isn't too careful in how they transfer public & private keys.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann Quel cauchemar! I have enough trouble with just one computer in just one place. :)

Comment: Thanks that really worked. I was pretty close to throwing my computer out the window

Comment: @jking14 I think we've all felt that way on this one. Oh, and wait until your annual membership has to be renewed. It's sheer hell...

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, revoke your previous certificates and then go through the process of requesting certificates again.  You'll have to regenerate your provisioning profiles after the new developer / distribution certificates are issued, though.

You start by going to the "Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles" section of your account at https://developer.apple.com/account/overview.action.

After you revoke the previous certificate, you can click "+" (in the upper right hand corner of the Certificates screen on Apple's portal) to add a brand new iOS certificate (and there will be instructions there that tell you what to do.

Comment: Snap! Looks like you've experienced this recently too (or else you just have a great memory for what happens when you do experience it).